# Erro ao realizar uma requisição SOAP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Olá, boa tarde!

Estou tentando realizar uma requisição SOAP com a webservice da TNT, mas estou obtendo um erro e não sei o que fazer.

Segue o meu código:

```
$cliente = new SoapClient('http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl');
$funcao = 'calculaFrete';
$parametros = array('calculaFrete' => array('in0' => array(
            'cdDivisaoCliente'                 => 7,
            'cepDestino'                       => '36213000',
            'cepOrigem'                        => '36213000',
            'login'                            => 'contato@uaiartesanatos.com.br',
            'nrIdentifClienteDest'             => '00000000000',
            'nrIdentifClienteRem'              => '28672407000190',
            'nrInscricaoEstadualDestinatario'  => '0000000000000',
            'nrInscricaoEstadualRemetente'     => '0086585810022',
            'psReal'                           => 15,
            'senha'                            => '',
            'tpFrete'                          => 'C',
            'tpPessoaDestinatario'             => 'F',
            'tpPessoaRemetente'                => 'J',
            'tpServico'                        => 'RNC',
            'tpSituacaoTributariaDestinatario' => 'CO',
            'tpSituacaoTributariaRemetente'    => 'CO',
            'vlMercadoria'                     => 650.17,
        )));
$resultado = null;      
$resultado = $cliente->__soapCall($funcao, $parametros);
```

Está dando o seguinte erro

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns0:Server] java.lang.NullPointerException in C:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\index.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\index.php(27): SoapClient->__soapCall('calculaFrete', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\index.php on line 27
```

Vale ressaltar que este código funcionava desde 2018, mas nas últimas semanas começou a dar este erro, alguém saberia informar o que estou fazendo de errado??

Desde já agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se ajudar, acabo de conseguir consumir o ws da TNT implementando este código:

```
$xmlr = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.calculoFrete.mercurio.com" xmlns:mod="http://model.vendas.lms.mercurio.com">
               <soapenv:Header/>
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <ser:calculaFrete>
                     <ser:in0>
                        <mod:login>' . $user_login . '</mod:login>
                        <mod:senha></mod:senha>
                        <mod:nrIdentifClienteRem>' . $cnpj . '</mod:nrIdentifClienteRem>
                        <mod:nrIdentifClienteDest>' . $idclientedest . '</mod:nrIdentifClienteDest>
                        <mod:tpFrete>' . $tipo_frete . '</mod:tpFrete>
                        <mod:tpServico>' . $tipo_servico . '</mod:tpServico>
                        <mod:cepOrigem>' . $cep_origem . '</mod:cepOrigem>
                        <mod:cepDestino>' . $cep_dst . '</mod:cepDestino>
                        <mod:vlMercadoria>' . number_format($valor_nf, 2, '.', '') . '</mod:vlMercadoria>
                        <mod:psReal>' . number_format($peso_total, 3, '.', '') . '</mod:psReal>
                        <mod:nrInscricaoEstadualRemetente>' . $ie . '</mod:nrInscricaoEstadualRemetente>
                        <mod:nrInscricaoEstadualDestinatario></mod:nrInscricaoEstadualDestinatario>
                        <mod:tpSituacaoTributariaRemetente>' . $situacao_trib . '</mod:tpSituacaoTributariaRemetente>
                        <mod:tpSituacaoTributariaDestinatario>CO</mod:tpSituacaoTributariaDestinatario>
                        <mod:cdDivisaoCliente>' . $divisao_cliente . '</mod:cdDivisaoCliente>
                        <mod:tpPessoaRemetente>' . $tipo_pessoa . '</mod:tpPessoaRemetente>
                        <mod:tpPessoaDestinatario>F</mod:tpPessoaDestinatario>
                     </ser:in0>
                  </ser:calculaFrete>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>';

// Chama o webservice                               
$location_URL = 'http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl';
$uri = 'http://service.calculoFrete.mercurio.com';
$action_URL = 'http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br/tntws/CalculoFrete';

$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
        'location' => $location_URL,
        'uri'      => $uri,
        'trace'    => 1,
        ));

$xml = $client->__doRequest($xmlr, $location_URL, $action_URL, 1);

// Le o XML
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');
$dom->loadXml($xml);

// Obtem os dados
$municipio = $dom->getElementsByTagName('nmMunicipioDestino')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$vltotal = $dom->getElementsByTagName('vlTotalFrete')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$prazo = $dom->getElementsByTagName('prazoEntrega')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Ajudou demais, com este código funcionou direitinho, já estava perdendo a cabeça depois que meu código parou de funcionar, muito obrigado mesmo!!!